# Break out of Ruby Find.find loop when condition met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, find, enumeration

I'm iterating through a large directory of files with:

```
Find.find('/some/path/to/directory/root') do |path|
  # ...do stuff with files…
end
```

What's a good way to limit the size of this enumerable group to `500` (or break out in some other way) if, say, `Rails.env.development?`?

I could use a counter but what's "the Ruby way"?

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
Find.find('/some/path/to/directory/root').first(500).each do |path|
  # do something
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`Find.find` enumerates the files; In other words it wants to loop over all of them. You can tack on an index value using:

```
Find.find(ENV['HOME']).with_index(1) do |path, i|
  puts path
  break if i > 10
end

puts 'done'
```

and use that to keep track of how many you've processed.

If you want to "do 'em all":

```
limit = <some number>

do_em_all = (limit == 0)
Find.find(ENV['HOME']).with_index(1) do |path, i|
  puts path
  break unless (do_em_all || i <= limit)
end

puts 'done'
```

If `limit` is `0` you'll process everything. If it's `> 0` you'll loop `limit` times.

You can also use [`Dir.entries`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html) or `Dir.glob` which will return an array of entries that you can slice apart as you want.

Enumerable's [`each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) could be useful at that point.

Comment: This works too! So many files (hundreds of thousands) that I think lazy loading will be the way to go...

Comment: I'm experimenting with it right now to confirm/deny whether Find.find will actually act lazily. It looked like it in the docs but reality seems to be different, at least in the debugger's reality.

Comment: It's not clear to me what to replace `500` with if I'm in production and do NOT want to limit the results?!? I've tried both `take(0)` (returns empty array) and `take(-1)` (returns error).

Comment: files = if Rails.env.production?; Find.find(..); else; Find.find(..).first(500); end; files.each do |f|; ...; end

Comment: @farleyknight - a conditional! guess that'll have to do. thx!